# Raising to subject or Subject control?

Tags: syntax

I'm trying to figure out whether the verb in bold below is a Raising to Subject or Subject control verb.

> The boys **were rumored** to have done so.

If it were **was rumored**, I could see more clearly that it's a Raising to Subject verb.  You could do the expletive It test - "It was rumored that the boys did so".  But since it's **were**, would that affect it in any way?  It's being affected by the subject.  You can't say "It were rumored to have done so."

Comment: It's **not** Raising to Subject (A-Raising). It's Raising to Object (B-Raising), followed by Passive and indefinite subject deletion. Original structure: _`indef` rumored [(for the boys) to have done so]_ --> _`indef` rumored the boys [to have done so]_ --> _the boys were rumored (by `indef`) [to have done so]_. See the [Cliff's on Equi and Raising](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the expletive insertion could work for `The boy was rumoured` but not for `The boys were rumoured`. Your test sentence `It was rumoured that the boys did so` indeed proves that `be rumoured` is a **raising predicate**. Look at your wrong result: `*It were rumoured to have done so`. Of course it's unacceptable because it doesn't have the (CP) that-clause that you used in the correct expletive test. If I recall correctly, this kind of clauses prevent the subject to be raised, but the expletive comes to the rescue. The verb has to agree with the expletive, not with a noun phrase that is blocked for movement. That's why you get `it was` and not `*it were`.